# How to use Pydoc to generate an HTML page?

Tags: python, pydoc

I have tried this and it writes the documentation to standard out.

```
 python -m pydoc pydoc_learning
```

*pydoc_learning* is the file that I wrote. I need to get this to show up on an HTML file similar to javadoc.

This is what I want my Pydoc output to look like:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO!

Have a good read here and come back and edit the question:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

Go to your folder and try:

```
pydoc -w pydoc_learning
```

It should generate an .html file

Answer (score 1):

Your first shot should be `pydoc --help` which is a fairly standard modern way to get help from a command line tool. You can try this with any other commands you have to learn about. When you come to write your own command line tools you would do well to consider adding such an option to your own tools.

Even when a tool does not explicitly support help with either `--help` or `-h` (such as `pydoc`), they sometimes help with option hints when given unsupported input. This is the case with `pydoc`.

On a unixy system you can also try `man` (short for manual as in manual page).